# Is there a better way to get a frequently accessed model than Model::whereName('name')->first()?

Tags: php, laravel

Sorry that the question isn't more specific, but I'm not quite sure what I'm after. I have a `grant()` function on my `User` model that initiates a transfer of funds from a source account into the user's account. One of the parameters of the function is a `TransactionType`. What I want to be able to call is something like:

```php
$user->grant(100000000, TransactionType::LotteryWin)
```

without calling

```php
$user->grant(100000000, TransactionType:whereName('lottery_win')->first())
```

What would be the best way to do this? I could maybe achieve it with `scopes`, but I'd like to know if there is a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is ok to do it with a scope. It's even perfectly fine to return a database result from a scope. In `TransactionType` make a scope:

```
public function scopeLotteryWin($query)
{
    // Do what you need here
    return $query->whereName('lottery_win')->first();
}
```

and then you can get that result with:

```
TransactionType::lotteryWin();
```